# Adjusting zoom in jsreport 2.0

Tags: jsreport

We have a fairly complex report running in hosted jsreportonline.net using Phantomjs 1.9.8. Over the past couple of days it 'broke' - I'm guessing due to an upgrade on that site.

It is now zoomed so that it is about 25% of the size it should be.

I've been playing around with CSS zooming etc to try and rectify with no luck.

I'm wondering if someone has any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no updates in jsreportonline four a long time so the service itself is hardly the cause of the zoom change.

The reason could be that you run the phantomjs rendering on linux and it did run on windows previously. Try to select different phantomjs version in the menu.

[image]

Another option is that you use a css from the cdn and the css was in the meantime updated. Make sure you link exact version, not the latest.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I think that you were right about the CSS. I was linking to a 'non versioned' URL. Rookie mistake!! :-)